# Failure delivering result ResultInfo after taking picture

Tags: android, android-fragments, camera, nullpointerexception, onactivityresult

I have a `Fragment` that allows to take pictures. Some of the fragments have a regular picture, and an extra picture. Meaning that I use two different `RESULT CODES` for which picture I am taking. The error I get is only when I take use the `RESULT_PICTURE_EXTRA` code and it seems random.

Why am I getting this error when I use the `REQUEST_PICTURE_EXTRA`? Also, if it helps, I am showing this picture in a `PopupWindow` and it doesn't show up.

**Fragment Code**

```
private static final int REQUEST_PICTURE = 1;
private static final int REQUEST_PICTURE_EXTRA = 2;

private void showExtraPicture() {
    ImageView extraImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.extra_image);

    if (step.getIsReqPictureFinished()) {
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = getActivity().openFileInput(step.getExtraImageFilename());
            Bitmap imgFromFile = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
            fis.close();
            extraImage.setImageBitmap(imgFromFile);
            extraImage.invalidate();
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) { e.printStackTrace(); } 
        catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_PICTURE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap image = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");

        ImageHandler imageHandler = new ImageHandler(getActivity());
        String filename = imageHandler.writeToFile(image, step.getChecklistId(), step.getOrder(), false);
        step.setImageFilename(filename);

        finishStep();
        showResult();
        checkIfAllFinished();
    }

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_PICTURE_EXTRA && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap image = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");

        ImageHandler imageHandler = new ImageHandler(getActivity());
        String filename = imageHandler.writeToFile(image, step.getChecklistId(), step.getOrder(), true);
        step.setExtraImageFilename(filename);

        if (step.getReqPicture()) { step.setIsReqPictureFinished(true); }
        showExtraPicture();
        checkIfAllFinished();
    }
}
```

**Stack Trace**

```
01-31 14:42:54.192: E/AndroidRuntime(21536): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-31 14:42:54.192: E/AndroidRuntime(21536): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=android:fragment:0, request=2, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data dat=content://media/external/images/media/3504 (has extras) }} to activity {com.medusa.checkit.android/com.medusa.checkit.android.StepActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-31 14:42:54.192: E/AndroidRuntime(21536):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3205)
01-31 14:42:54.192: E/AndroidRuntime(21536):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3248)
01-31 14:42:54.192: E/AndroidRuntime(21536):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:143)
01-31 14:42:54.192: E/AndroidRuntime(21536):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289)
01-31 14:42:54.192: E/AndroidRuntime(21536):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-31 14:42:54.192: E/AndroidRuntime(21536):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-31 14:42:54.192: E/AndroidRuntime(21536):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
01-31 14:42:54.192: E/AndroidRuntime(21536):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-31 14:42:54.192: E/AndroidRuntime(21536):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-31 14:42:54.192: E/AndroidRuntime(21536):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
01-31 14:42:54.192: E/AndroidRuntime(21536):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
01-31 14:42:54.192: E/AndroidRuntime(21536):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-31 14:42:54.192: E/AndroidRuntime(21536): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-31 14:42:54.192: E/AndroidRuntime(21536):    at com.medusa.checkit.android.StepFragment.showExtraPicture(StepFragment.java:388)
01-31 14:42:54.192: E/AndroidRuntime(21536):    at com.medusa.checkit.android.StepFragment.onActivityResult(StepFragment.java:547)
01-31 14:42:54.192: E/AndroidRuntime(21536):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5367)
01-31 14:42:54.192: E/AndroidRuntime(21536):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3201)
01-31 14:42:54.192: E/AndroidRuntime(21536):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read your error message: a `NullPointerException` occurs inside `showExtraPicture()`. That's why it only happens with `REQUEST_PICTURE_EXTRA` code.

You need to find what's `null` and why. This is on line 388, so only you know, but I'd bet on `view` being `null`.

Whether it is or not anyway, you shouldn't hold onto your created root `View` (assuming this is what `view` reference here is). Just find your views from the attached `Activity` each time you need it:

```
getActivity().findViewById(R.id.extra_image);
```

or from the fragment's root view works too if `R.id.extra_image` is held inside it:

```
getView().findViewById(R.id.extra_image);
```

And, as a side note, you should close resources in finally: see the example in [FileInputStream documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileInputStream.html).

Comment: you are correct, I was setting the wrong view for it. Also, why should you not use the created root `View`? I tried to use `getActivity()` but it would crash, probably because I am using a `Fragment`.

Comment: `getActivity()` is a method of `Fragment`s, so it should work there. It may return `null` before the fragment is attached to the activity (or after it is detached), but if you called it in `onActivityResult()` it should return the activity so your crash may be something else. If `R.id.extra_image` is defined inside the layout your fragment returns in `onCreateView()`, then you can also get it from the fragment root view: `getView().findViewById(R.id.extra_image);`.

Comment: The created root view can be used, I recommended getting it dynamically via `getView()` simply as "good" programming style: to not "leak" it to a wider scope (the fragment) than the one it was created (`onCreateView()`), and in case it would change in course of the fragment life. In this use case though, the view wouldn't leak for long (just after `onDestroyView()`, but at this time the fragment is about to be destroyed anyway) nor would the root view change afterwards, so this is OK. It's just a good habit to take I think.